# How to combine 2 or more docx file in single docx file using shell

Tags: linux, shell, docx

I came across a scenario where I have to combine 2 or more docx file in one docx file from command line. I tried to use basic cmd

```
cat file1.docx file2.docx file3.docx > final_file.docx
```

but it didn't work. Above command just copied the last file which is file3.docx into final_file.docx. I need a help to solve this problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Use >> to append as opposed to > which will overwrite.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) in a way similar to that mentioned on Paul's answer.

```
pandoc *docx -o combined.docx
```

This should combine all Word documents in the folder, in alphabetical order, I believe, to create a single document.

Comment: The main problem with my solution here, however, is that pandoc will reformat the document.

Comment: Under windows without -s it doesnt works. I try this and it's ok : pandoc -s input1.docx input2.docx -o combined.docx

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that. DOCX files have specific info for start and end.
If you have a way to convert the DOCX files to markdown files (.md), you could use pandoc to create 1 DOCX from them:

pandoc *md -o document.docx.

Answer (score 1):

There is a few tools on github for that!

- https://github.com/jamessantiago/DocxMerge (release contains `.exe` for Windows, you can try to build it for your system)
- https://github.com/tymbaca/pagemerger (you can grab and install `.deb` package from [release](https://github.com/tymbaca/pagemerger/releases/tag/v1.0.0))

---

For second example you can merge `docx` with following command:

```bash
pagemerger output.docx src_file1.docx src_file2.docx src_file3.docx
```

If you want to add page breaks between merged files, just use `-b` option, like so:

```bash
pagemerger -b output.docx src_file1.docx src_file2.docx src_file3.docx
```